# Method returns null values despite having a value before return

Tags: c#, list, reference, ref

I took a liberty of copying [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-to-find-all-subsets/) code and adjusted it to C#

```cs
private static List<List<int>> Subsets(List<int> A)
        {
            List<int> subset = new List<int>();
            List<List<int>> res = new List<List<int>>();

            int index = 0;
            SubsetsUtil(A, ref res, ref subset, index);
            //here res becomes "empty"
            return res;
        }

        private static void SubsetsUtil(List<int> A, ref List<List<int>> res, ref List<int> subset, int index)
        {
            if (subset.Count > 0)
            {
                res.Add(subset);
            }

            for (int i = index; i < A.Count(); i++)
            {
                // include the A[i] in subset. 
                subset.Add(A[i]);

                // move onto the next element. 
                SubsetsUtil(A, ref res, ref subset, i + 1);

                // exclude the A[i] from subset and triggers 
                // backtracking. 
                subset.RemoveAt(subset.Count - 1);
            }
            return;
        }
```

On paper it looks amazing, but for some reason `Subsets` method returns `list` that contains proper count of subsets, but they are all empty. When I placed some traps inside `SubsetsUtil` method results are actually saving properly to `res` variable, but after `SubsetsUtil` method is finished inside `Subsets`, `res` no longer contains it.

I have absolutely no idea how to fix it, it looks like a glitch in environment, but I'm pretty sure I'm just missing some little tiny detail.

Comment: You don't need to pass those lists with ref as you're not assigning new list instances.

Comment: @ekke removing ref changes nothing, and actually makes it obviously wrong. Because then all calculations are lost and it returns fully empty List<List<int>>.

Comment: No, ekke is correct.  your code makes the lists fully empty either way.  Your problem is that you add the same subset list each time you add to res, then on that same subset, which will be added A.Count times to res, you eventually remove every item in subset.

Comment: I think you need to create `subset` inside of the method so that each recursive call is creating a new list instead of reusing the same one over and over again.

Comment: @Perro12 No they're not, that's not how reference types work in C#. See here for an excellent explanation http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx.

Comment: @Russ I definitely can be wrong, but then how `res` loses this result after? Its saved inside, after leaving the function its gone, reduced to atoms.

Comment: @Perro12.  It's not res losing the result, it's subset.  When you call that RemoveAt, you are removing it from subset, which exists A.Count times in res.  You aren't adding a copy of subset to res, you are adding subset itself.  My guess is that you need to make a copy of subset and add that copy to res, instead.

Comment: Here's a good blog about getting all subsets of a certain length using C# which you can use to get all the subsets of all lengths just by looping through all the possible lengths https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/

Comment: @Russ I have literally slapped WriteLine and all results display one by one. I even saved it to "global" static variable, but also this global variable is losing it. I guess i broke c#. I can always move to python.